# Drag group element out of SVG canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag a group element out of an SVG canvas? 
In the example below I want to drag the element out of the SVG and fire an event so I can actually remove it from the canvas, kind of like the native HTML5 drag and drop.

```
<svg>
    <g class="highcharts-legend-item" transform="translate(8,3)" draggable="true"  ondragstart="dragChartLegend(event)">
        <path d="M 8 7 C 13 7 13 15 8 15 C 2 15 2 7 8 7 Z"></path>
     </g>
    <g class="highcharts-legend-item" transform="translate(32,3)" draggable="true"  ondragstart="dragChartLegend(event)">
        <path d="M 8 7 C 13 7 13 15 8 15 C 2 15 2 7 8 7 Z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
<script>
    function dragChartLegend(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I suppose you could have a handler on the div or whatever external space, set a flag when dragging, and if you trigger the other handler, hide/remove the element being dragged ?

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your reply. I've made my example a bit better. The div isn't important - I have several groups inside the canvas I want to be able to drag.